# how to remove existing field like 'name' in catalog->manage products->general tab for magento 1.5?

Tags: magento

i want to remove some fields like description,short description from catalog->Manage Products->continue->general tab in admin panel...here i can add new field but can't delete existing fields..i tried so much but finally i am not getting the right page where i have insert or delete the code for making/removing fields.Can Anybody help me...with best regards....

Comment: You really need to accept answers to some of your previous questions.  Otherwise people will stop answering.  It's how StackOverflow works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name, description, short description, etc are the **system attributes**. You cannot delete them from admin panel. However, you can delete them from database. Follow the article link below which explains on how to delete system attributes in Magento.

[**Magento: How to delete System Attribute?**](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-delete-system-attribute/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are system fields and are generally relied upon in other parts of the system, so they are not meant to be removed. Can you give more detail about why you are trying to do this?

Comment: i want to remove price tab from product and will use price with variations only.Can you tell me how the fileds are developed in general tab ,whether from database or some other pages.Please help me..thanks

Comment: You cannot remove the price tab, prices are intrinsic to the framework. Any attempt to not use prices will cause chaos in the framework. The data is generally pulled from the database, but is relied upon so heavily in the framework that you *will* break it by removing this data.

Comment: thanks joseph...please answer me another problem,i have added an attribute as category in default attribute set to show in product page,i want to make this attribute category to be visible for all attribut set...though i made this attribute  as global yet it is not visible for all attribute set.

Comment: you have to add it to every attribute set that should have it.